# example.com VirtualHost on local machine

Tags: apache, web, virtualhost

**What I am trying to do** : To add a site (`example.com`) to `apache2/sites-available` (I have specified its document root) and then enable it and after that access it on my local machine (as `example.com` in browser). I have some following queries :

1. Is it possible to create a website and give a specific domain (`example.com`) to it?
2. What are the steps I need to follow in order to create a site, give a domain and access it on my local machine ONLY?

**NOTE:** I have the content of site. I want to create a new site and I do not want to change the **default** site(i.e. `apache2/sites-available/default`) of Apache.

**UPDATE:**

I faced a error while restarting Apache (I have added a `VirtualHost` as described)

ERROR

```
CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" clause (see docs)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

My site's file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName dev.subhransu.com

        ScriptAlias /private /home/hg/repositories/private/hgweb.cgi
        <Directory /home/hg/repositories/private/>
                Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                DirectoryIndex hgweb.cgi
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Mercurial repositories"
                AuthUserFile /home/hg/tools/hgusers
                Require valid-user
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.subhransu.com_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, cr$
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.subhransu.com_ssl_access.lo$

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/dev.subhransu.com.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/dev.subhransu.com.k$

</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  dev.subhransu.com
ServerAlias www.dev.subhransu.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have a second argument for your CustomLog Directive?  The information in your vhost is cut off so I can't tell what you have placed at the end of your CustomLog directive.  Here is an example of a CustomLog Directive:  `CustomLog "/path/to/log/file/logs/access.log" combined`

Answer (score 1):

In `httpd.conf` (or vhosts), the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` settings are what domain names Apache will respond to

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

then just edit your hosts file to point `example.com` to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

I think the feature you may be looking for is vhosts.  With vhosts you can create any number of sites, each setup independently of the other.  For each vhost you can specify the 'ServerName' directive which is your domain, which can be anything you want it to be.  And then in your computers hosts file you can route all your calls for that domain to localhost.

If you only have one site that you need to setup, just edit the default apache configuration, leaving vhosts alone, and then update the hosts file on your machine as I mentioned earlier.

References:
[vhost examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)
[How to edit your hosts file](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)